# max_rows on mysql partitioning

Tags: mysql

I am try to set up a mysql partition like so:

```
PARTITION BY LINEAR KEY(id) PARTITIONS 100 MAX_ROWS=1000000
```

But I get the following error:

> The server has returned this error message:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MAX_ROWS=1000000' at line 36

How does one use max_rows on mysql partitioning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAX_ROWS is a per-partition option. The rest of your query snippet is part of the partition definition block.

```
PARTITION BY LINEAR KEY (id) PARTITIONS 100 (PARTITION part_1 MAX_ROWS=1000000)
```

Language spec is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html), search for `partition_options:`